# SSIS - Loading Japanese Double byte data from DB2 to SQL Server 2017 is giving conversion error

Tags: sql, ssis, db2, cjk

I am trying import data from DB2 which has double byte Japanese(1027) data into SQL Server 2017 using SSIS

Tried using data conversion before inserting data "`932 (ANSI/OEM - Japanese Shift- JIS)`". Tried using Unicode `string[DT_WSTR]` still the same issue

> [Data Conversion [2]] Error: Data conversion failed while converting column "ABC" (286) to column "A\cABC"(38).  The conversion returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page.".

Comment: I think you might find this blog post very helpful: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charliee/2008/10/31/db2-code-page-fun/